# validatate param input to make sure its a text file

Tags: validation, powershell, input

one of a mandatory parameters for my PS script is to accept a text file name of a list of servers. How do I validate the input param to make sure it is a text file type with .txt extension? If not a txt file then I will exit the script and inform user accordingly.

So it will be something like this but not sure how to validate between the If statement:

```
process
{
    if  (....)
    {
        throw "$($Filename) must be a txt file with .txt extension"
    }
}
```

Comment: To place your code in a code block so that your formatting will be rendered properly, select the code and click the **{}** in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

Two options. The first way, if the specified filename doesn't exist, it will throw an error saying that the path doesn't exist regardless of the extension:

```
process 
{
    if ((Get-Item $filename -ErrorAction Stop).Extension -ne '.txt') 
    {
      throw "$($filename) must be a txt file with .txt extension"
    }
}
```

Another way to do it, just checking whether **$filename** has a .txt extension, regardless of whether it exists:

```
process 
{
    if (-not $filename.EndsWith('.txt'))
    {
      throw "$($filename) must be a txt file with .txt extension"
    }
}
```

This way, you'll need to handle the question of whether the file exists later, but you might prefer this if you want to throw the error about the extension as well as about the nonexistence of the file when a nonexistent file that doesn't end with .txt is specified.

Comment: I'd add `-EA Stop` to `Get-Item` to make the cmdlet terminate if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking that he might want to throw the error about the extension if a non-.txt filename is specified regardless of whether the file exists, but this code will throw both errors if the file *does* have a .txt extension and doesn't exist. So if he wants to throw this error message in either case, he should just invoke **.EndsWith** on **$filename**. I'll modify the answer to offer both options.

Answer (score 2):

Post from phone, may contain errors ..

```
param(
[parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[validatescript({(Get-Item $_).Extension -eq '.txt'})]
$filename
)
```

/M

Comment: The problem with parameter validation is that if it fails, it just displays the criteria that weren't met (the scriptblock, in this case). It doesn't let you provide a descriptive error message unless you get really fancy about it.